# Using tangent to calculate a length of a right-angled triangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

[image: diagram of rectangle with sheared image]

My calculation:

$$\tan(30^\circ)=\frac{2}{x_A'}$$
$$x_A'=\frac{2}{\tan(30^\circ)}$$
$$x_A'=\sqrt{3}$$

But the answer is:

$x_A'=2\sqrt{3}-1$.

I'm wondering what step I'm missing in regards to the $-1$.

Comment: If $x_{A}'$ is meant to be the $x$ co-ordinate of $C'$, then would you not need to subtract from the horizontal length (which is what your calculated $x_{A}'$ actually is) the distance that $D'$ is from the origin, which is $1$?

Comment: Note the $C'$ in my comment above should have been $A'$ instead.

Comment: Why was my question downvoted? If I made any mistakes in presenting my question let me know so I can avoid doing this again in the future.

@JohnOmielan (and everyone who answered on this thread) --  thanks for the insights, it's been really helpful.

Comment: You're welcome for any insight my comment provided to you. Regarding the downvote of your question, since I didn't do that, I can't give any reason(s) why it it happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\tan(30^\circ)=\frac{2}{x_A'}$$
$$x_A'=\frac{2}{\tan(30^\circ)}=2 \sqrt{3}$$
Look at x- projection of $O$ and $A'$
$$ x _{O-A'}= x'A-1= 2 \sqrt{3}-1$$

Answer (score 1):

The length of the top edge of the triangle is $x_A'+1$.
$$\sqrt{3} = \tan(60^\circ) = \frac{x_A'+1}{2}$$
$$x_A'=2\sqrt{3}-1$$

Answer (score 0):

The length of the hypotenuse $D'A'$ of right triangle $\triangle D'AA'$ can be found using the slope formula.

Given coordinates $(x_{D'},y_{D'})=(-1,0)$  and $(x_{A'},y_{A'})=(x_{A'},2)$ the slope of the hypotenuse $D'A'$ is given by

\begin{eqnarray}
m&=&\frac{y_{A'}-y_{D'}}{x_{A'}-x_{D'}}\\
&=&\frac{2}{x_{A'}+1}
\end{eqnarray}

But we are know also that $m=\tan{30^\circ}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$

So

$$\frac{2}{x_{A'}+1}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$$

Solving gives $x_{A'}=2\sqrt{3}-1$.